# Local yum repo for multiple versions

Tags: redhat, yum, local

I would like to setup a local repo for rhel 5 and 6. Can this be done on 1 server, or do I need one server for each major version?

We have a valid, legal subscription with RH, but we would rather not pay for RH satellite.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* build packages for EL5 on an EL6 box, but the problem is that EL6 has a newer version of RPM that writes files incompatible with the version of RPM shipped with EL5. You can work around this with some arguments to `rpmbuild` when building your source packages, preferably in a wrapper script. Something like this will cause `rpmbuild` to use the older format:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assumes you have an RPM environment set up in ~/rpmbuild using rpmdev-setuptree
# Argument 1: a spec file in ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
# Build the EL6 SRPM
rpmbuild -bs $1
# Build the EL5 SRPM
rpmbuild \
  --define "_source_filedigest_algorithm 1" \
  --define "_binary_filedigest_algorithm 1" \
  --define "_binary_payload w9.gzdio" \
  --define="dist .el5" \
  --define="el5 1" \
  $1
```

Once the SRPMs are built, you can then run `mock` on the EL5 and EL6 SRPMs, respectively:

```
for el in 5 6; do
  for package in ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/*.el{$el}.src.rpm; do
    for arch in x86_64 i386; do
      mock -r epel-{$el}-{$arch} $package
    done
  done
done
```

Comment: I don't think we will be doing any package building - this would just be for OS updates and what not.

Comment: Oh, you just want a local mirror of the Red Hat packages? Sorry, you get to buy Satellite.

Comment: It's definitely possible to create a local yum repository to update your RHEL servers WITHOUT buying satellite..
This guy has an excellent guide: http://kenfallon.com/how-to-mirror-rhn-behind-your-firewall/

Comment: @chris That might work, but it's not supported by Red Hat, and it also could be used for piracy. So I wouldn't mention it here.